# How to initialize Spring application context file in Selenium TestNG environment

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

How to initialize a Spring application context File in Selenium TestNG environment in Spring 5?

I tried the following code, but it's using classpathapplicationcontext, so every build will delete the application context file.

```
 public class SpringInitManager {
        private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;

    public void init() {// "classpath:applicationContext.xml"
        setCtx(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml"));
    }
    // 
    public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }
    // 
    public void setCtx(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

It works in Eclipse, but not in IntelliJ.

Comment: What do you mean with _"I tried the following code, but it's using classpathapplicationcontext, so every build will delete the application context file"_? Because that is not how it works if you put the file in the right location. Please describe exactly what you're doing and where your files are.

Comment: Please share more code snippets for understanding which test case you are trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, without test code snippets, you should change the test classes as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class TestNGSpringTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
   //testNG test methods...
}
```

Annotation `ContextConfiguration` configures how to load Spring context for integration tests and  `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` class integrates the Spring TestContext Framework with explicit `ApplicationContext` testing support in a TestNG environment.